# Can't start a libgdx desktop project

Tags: java, libgdx, classnotfoundexception

I'm developing an Android application with Libgdx. Everything has gone good so far (I've been debugging in the emulator), but I came to a point where I needed to set up a desktop project, so I could test the app faster (so instead of running it on an emulator, I could test it on a desktop app).

I made the setup just as the wiki says, adding the desktop version, and everything has gone good so far, no compiler errors. But when I try to launch the desktop app, I get the following error, without even opening a window:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/Net
    at DesktopGame.main(DesktopGame.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.Net
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

The line 12 of the DesktopGame.java says:

```
new LwjglApplication(new UserStart(userID, appDefinitions), "Game", 1024, 600, false);
```

Where UserStart is the ApplicationListener (with a custom constructor as I needed a couple of parameters, this setup works well on Android). I don't know why com.badlogic.gdx.Net is not found (and I don't know why it is looking for it as I'm not using network features).

Does anyone know what could it be? Thanks!

Comment: I've never used Libgdx myself, but this looks like the library jar file for Libgdx is not being linked into your application.  Take a look at your classpath settings and/or the manifest file of your application's jar.

Comment: do you have the required libgdx jars in the "libs" folder? For the desktop project you need gdx-natives.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar and gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar, remember to get these jars not the sources.

Comment: @Jimmt Yes, I have the libgdx jars in the libs folder and linked in teh build path. Also the main project (the one that has the gdx.jar linked and exported) is added.

Comment: @Tansir1 The strange thing is that most of the imports work well. The autocomplete at Eclipse shows me most of the libgdx classes except com.badlogic.gdx.Net

Comment: @Jimmt Refreshed, cleaned and rebuilt several times :/

Comment: wait, are you sure it actually exists? i can't find it on the api...maybe it's the internet filter

Comment: @Jimmt I have no idea if "com.badlogic.gdx.Net" exists or not to be honest. But if it doesn't, then I'm more surprised that it tries to load it.

Comment: If you go to "Referenced Libraries" under your main project in Eclipse then you should see gdx.jar. Open that and navigate to com.badlogic.gdx, then expand that to find Net.class. If it isn't there, then try reimporting gdx.jar into your project.

Comment: maybe you just didn't add your libs in properties. it happened for android version of libGDX. maybe you must do this for your desktop too. something like [This](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2362)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! Well, kind of. I created a new project using the setup UI from libgdx, and then copied the created desktop project to my own project. I noticed that the main difference was on which constructor I was using for the LwjglApplication, now in this case, instead of passing the parameters, I called the constructor with a LwjglApplicationConfiguration:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.title = "MyGame";
cfg.useGL20 = false;
cfg.width = 480;
cfg.height = 320;

...
new LwjglApplication(new UserStart(userID, appDefinitions), cfg);
```

Yay! I'm not sure if this was the main issue, but at least now works.

Thanks everybody for the comments and tips.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the gradle plugin for the eclipse and my problem was solved.
Gradle plugin can be added by following the instructions on this link http://estiloasertivo.blogspot.com/2013/03/tutorial-howto-install-and-configure.html